# Example SQL queries in mORMot

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi, delphi-7, mormot

I'm using [Synopse mORMot](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=Downloads) to access a SQLite database from Delphi 7. I wish to establish a connection and query the database directly via SQL without using the ORM (Object-relational mapping) features of mORMot.

Could you provide code examples which execute SQL queries without relying on the ORM functionality of mORMot?

Comment: What exactly is your question, or what do you want us to tell you?

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick , I want, that to me gave examples of SQL queries without ORM use in mORMot.

Answer (score 8):

In short: it is better to use the `SynDB.pas` layer over `SynSQLite3.pas`, via its `SynDBSQLite3.pas` classes, since it will allow your code to work in the future with any database accessible via OleDB / ODBC or even direct access (e.g. for Oracle).

For instance, using a variant for holding column data:

```
procedure Test(Props: TSQLDBConnectionProperties);
var Customer: Variant;
begin
  with Props.Execute('select * from Customers where AccountNumber like ?',
    ['AW000001%'],@Customer) do
    while Step do
      assert(Copy(Customer.AccountNumber,1,8)='AW000001');
end;

var Props: TSQLDBConnectionProperties;

  Props := TSQLDBSQLite3ConnectionProperties.Create('databasefile.db3','','','');
  try
    Test(Props);
  finally
    Props.Free;
  end;
```

So for your question, read the SynDB-related part of the *mORMot* documentation, and all the [related blog articles](http://blog.synopse.info/tag/SynDB). Those classes are used by the ORM, but you can use those without the ORM.

To start with, there is a `TQuery` wrapper in `SynDB.pas` which works very well with SQLite3 and allow "classic" code-level programming.

But there is not 100% RAD direct access with those units. Just some TClientDataSet "fillers". This was not their purpose: they want fast and direct access to the DB, in code, not via the UI plumbing.

Comment: SAD 1.18 Ch.25.4.2.   "...MVC features would not working directly" - either "would BE not working" or "would not WORK"

Comment: "Just before the application exists, add a call.. " - EXITS

Comment: Hello again. you were intereted in heap managers

can you spend some time trying this: http://www.sql.ru/forum/1213139-1/ekstremalno-bystryy-menedzher-pamyati-brainmm
  /// 
reportedly it is not yet asm-optimized, so more about generic scaling behaviour and stability